# Postgres Trigger over a FDW table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, amazon-rds

I wonder if I can create a trigger over a FDW table.

My target is:
Whenever something happens in a foreign table, I trigger an event in my local table (local server).
I'm using the FDW because I don't have write permissions in the source table (a remote one), so I'm using the FDW feature.
The `enterprises` table is a foreign.

I tried the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION INSERT_ENTERPRISE() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $INSERT_ENTERPRISE$
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO TEST_ENTERPRISES VALUES(NEW.ENTERPRISE_ID);
    END;
$INSERT_ENTERPRISE$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

and the trigger as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TG_INSERT_ENTERPRISE 
    BEFORE INSERT ON ENTERPRISES
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE INSERT_ENTERPRISE();
```

There is a lot of inserts happening in the remote table but no one in my local table.

Answer (score -1):

Since PostgreSQL version 9.4 you can define triggers on foreign tables.